# Storing img src in to a php variable

Tags: php, html, variables

So I'm completely new to PHP and coding in general.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

$barcode = <img src="barcode.php?text=$offerId" alt="$offerId"

</body>
</html>
```

I need this barcode img in to the variable. Which I will be echoing in another file. I don't know how to work with the php tags.

Comment: You're going to need some basic code there. You may want to take some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

All PHP code has to be inside php tags (`<?php   ?>`)

Everything outside those tags will be printed on the page.

There are some other mistakes in this little part.

1: declaring a varibale does not print (or in PHP-terms: echo) anything. use echo (as seen below)

2: When declaring a variable with a string, use quotes.

3: You did not close the img tag

Something like this could work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$barcode = '<img src="barcode.php?text='.$offerId.'" alt="'.$offerId.'">';
echo $barcode;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks. I just couldn't figure out how the quotes worked.